# Font Size in EM does not behave as expected for a VerticalPanel

Tags: css, gwt, font-size

I wish to fix one font-size in 'PX' in the start (let's say onModuleLoad) and have rest of the widgets and themes in 'EM'. This is to help me change the look and feel for different screen resolutions dynamically. Here's the sample code I was trying out.

```
    root = RootPanel.get();
    root.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(40, Unit.PX);
    root.setSize("100%", "100%");

    Label l = new Label("Hello World");
    l.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(1, Unit.EM);
    root.add(l);

    VerticalPanel vp = new VerticalPanel();
    root.add(vp);

    l = new Label("Hello World");
    l.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(1, Unit.EM);
    vp.add(l);
```

Ideally I would like both the labels of same font-size. But the second one is far smaller than the first one. But for the following code, it works as expected.

```
    root = RootPanel.get();
    root.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(40, Unit.PX);
    root.setSize("100%", "100%");

    Label l = new Label("Hello World");
    l.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(1, Unit.EM);
    root.add(l);

    SimplePanel vp = new SimplePanel();
    root.add(vp);

    l = new Label("Hello World");
    l.getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(1, Unit.EM);
    vp.add(l);
```

If this is the case, it seems I should be staying away from Vertical/Horizontal Panels if I wish to implement a generalized em. Also I tried FlexTable, but the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of the default GWT styles in your gwt.xml? It's possible your font size data is being overridden in more complex panels.

At any rate, I'm using a similar approach myself; what I did was, I basically just set the style for the whole HTML `body` right at the start of my CSS, setting the font size there in PX, then used EM everywhere else and that worked nicely for the most part.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Giving a constant width to body in css does solve the problem. But I wish this width to be dynamic based on different resolutions. I tried using RootPanel.getBodyElement.getStyle but that isn't helping.

Comment: You misunderstood, I meant set the font size for `body` in CSS! Elements inherit the font size property from their parent, an EM sizes are based on this, you'll want every element to have the same font size in PX.

Comment: By the way, you'll want to use `RootLayoutPanel`, `RootPanel` is for quirks mode used in old browsers; although technically I don't think you're using anything that shouldn't work on `RootPanel`, I'd still avoid it. See [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards) for a bit more info.

Comment: Yes, I did understand your suggestion that fixed size for `body` is to be applied in CSS. And I tried it, it does work. But what I was looking for is, applying fixed font-sizes to `body` based on client `resolution`. For e.g. body font-size of 12px for screens <=1280px, 14px for <=1600, and 16px for >1600. This way I can configure the font sizes in theme and custom css files in `em` thus making the look and feel of the entire site on different resolutions near about same.

Comment: You can either check the client size in code and load different CSS depending on what it is OR you can use the method [CSS has for this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media).